# Advent of Code 2022 Day 8, Part 1. My answer is not matching the answer expected, but I am getting the sample correct. Lost on where to go

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nested, grid

Here is the problem for advent of code 2022, Day 8.

```
The expedition comes across a peculiar patch of tall trees all planted carefully in a grid. The Elves explain that a previous expedition planted these trees as a reforestation effort. Now, they're curious if this would be a good location for a tree house.

First, determine whether there is enough tree cover here to keep a tree house hidden. To do this, you need to count the number of trees that are visible from outside the grid when looking directly along a row or column.

The Elves have already launched a quadcopter to generate a map with the height of each tree (your puzzle input). For example:

30373
25512
65332
33549
35390
Each tree is represented as a single digit whose value is its height, where 0 is the shortest and 9 is the tallest.

A tree is visible if all of the other trees between it and an edge of the grid are shorter than it. Only consider trees in the same row or column; that is, only look up, down, left, or right from any given tree.

All of the trees around the edge of the grid are visible - since they are already on the edge, there are no trees to block the view. In this example, that only leaves the interior nine trees to consider:

The top-left 5 is visible from the left and top. (It isn't visible from the right or bottom since other trees of height 5 are in the way.)
The top-middle 5 is visible from the top and right.
The top-right 1 is not visible from any direction; for it to be visible, there would need to only be trees of height 0 between it and an edge.
The left-middle 5 is visible, but only from the right.
The center 3 is not visible from any direction; for it to be visible, there would need to be only trees of at most height 2 between it and an edge.
The right-middle 3 is visible from the right.
In the bottom row, the middle 5 is visible, but the 3 and 4 are not.
With 16 trees visible on the edge and another 5 visible in the interior, a total of 21 trees are visible in this arrangement.

Consider your map; how many trees are visible from outside the grid?
```

And here is my code solving that:

```
with open('day8.in') as file:
    forest = file.read().strip()

trees = [list(x) for x in forest.split('\n')]

visible = (len(trees) - 1) * 4

for i in range(1, len(trees) - 1):
    for j in range(1, len(trees[i]) - 1):

        if trees[i][j] > trees[i][j - 1]:
            for k in range(j - 1, -1, -1):
                if trees[i][k] > trees[i][j]:
                    break
                if k == 0 and trees[i][k] < trees[i][j]:
                    visible += 1

        elif trees[i][j] > trees[i][j + 1]:
            for k in range(j + 1, len(trees[i])):
                if trees[i][k] > trees[i][j]:
                    break
                if k == len(trees[i]) - 1 and trees[i][k] < trees[i][j]:
                    visible += 1

        elif trees[i][j] > trees[i - 1][j]:
            for k in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
                if trees[k][j] > trees[i][j]:
                    break
                if k == 0 and trees[k][j] < trees[i][j]:
                    visible += 1

        elif trees[i][j] > trees[i + 1][j]:
            for k in range(i + 1, len(trees)):
                if trees[k][j] > trees[i][j]:
                    break
                if k == len(trees) - 1 and trees[k][j] < trees[i][j]:
                    visible += 1

print(visible)
```

I am getting 21 for the example which I should be getting, but with the actual input, it's saying my answer is not correct and I can't find out!

I tried printing throughout my code and from the example, it seems as if I was doing exactly what I wanted to do.

I checked for the actual input and I believe it was a 99x99 grid, so I believe my initial visible variable is correct too.

The actual input is too large for me to manually go through and figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues.

Firstly, for each loop, you're checking this:

```
if trees[i][k] > trees[i][j]:
    break
```

This is wrong, because the tree will ideally not be visible even if a tree of the same height is in the way. You should check for equality as well (`if trees[i][k] >= trees[i][j]`)

Secondly, your "if-elif" logic is wrong. Let's say a tree is greater in height than all 4 neighboring trees. You will only enter the first `if` block. However, if the tree isn't visible along that path, you won't check the other paths (that is, the other `elif` blocks). This would be an easy fix, so I'll leave it for the you to implement.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I see now, definitely forgot the logic if they were the same size! Thank you for helping me see that.